# Что я сделал не так?? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null

Tags: javascript

Есть динамическое модальное окно.
Оно закрывается 3 способами:

1. Нажатием на крестик
2. Нажатием на кнопку Esc
3. Нажатием левой кнопкой мыши вне зоны контента модального окна (Тут ошибка)

Первые два способа работают хорошо, а третий работает и закрывает модальное окно, но, начиная с второго закрытия, в консоли выбивает ошибка:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null

```js
function renderModal(title, parentSelector) {
  class ModalGG {
    constructor(title) {
      this.title = title;
      this.parent = document.querySelector(parentSelector);
    }
    render() {
      const element = document.createElement('div');
      element.id = 'divInner';

      element.innerHTML = `
                <div class="modal__content__gallery">
                    <div class="modal__close__gallery" id="modal__gallery__close">&times;</div>
                    <div class="modal__title__gallery">${this.title}</div>
                    <div class="wrapper__inner">
                        <div class="modal__gallery__photo">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x700" alt="">
                        </div>
                            <div class="modal__gallery__text">
                                <p>324111121341234</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;
      this.parent.append(element);
    }
  }
  new ModalGG(title, parentSelector).render();
}

function showModalGallery(title, parentSelector) {

  renderModal(title, parentSelector);
  modalGallery.style.display = 'block';

  //Close code
  var modalGalleryClose = document.querySelector('#modal__gallery__close');
  var divInner = document.querySelector('#divInner');

  // Закрыть крестиком
  modalGalleryClose.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    hideModalGallery();
  })

  //Закрыть модальный окно нажатием на кнопку Esc
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.code === "Escape" && modalDialogGallery.contains(divInner)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      hideModalGallery();
    }
  });

  //закрыть модальный окно нажатием на зону по модульному окном
  modalGallery.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === modalGallery || e.target.modalGalleryClose == '') {
      hideModalGallery();
    }
  });
}

function hideModalGallery() {
  modalGallery.style.display = 'none';

  var divInner = document.querySelector('#divInner');
  divInner.remove();
}

//Открыть модальное окно
picture.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  showModalGallery('title1', ".modal__gallery .modal__dialog__gallery");
});
```

```html
<div class="modal__gallery" id="modalGallery">
  <div class="modal__dialog__gallery" id="modal__dialog__gallery">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Каждый раз при открытии модалки вы добавляете слушателя на клик

```
//закрыть модальный окно нажатием на зону по модульному окном
  modalGallery.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === modalGallery || e.target.modalGalleryClose == '') {
      hideModalGallery();
    }
  });
```

в итоге при втором закрытии дважды срабатывает `hideModalGallery();`
при первом запуске он удаляет `'#divInner'` а при втором возвращает ошибку так как не может удалить его тк его уже нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Я исправил эту ошибку таким способом:
Вынес третий способ за пределы функции showModalGallery ();

Comment: @MaxDuma Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.